# How do I access posted form data and files when using Shelf?

Tags: dart, dart-shelf

New to Dart and writing an HTTP server using Shelf and I can't seem to find a straightforward way to grab my posted form data (and uploads) from the `Request` object -- not sure why a simple thing like this has been deliberately made hard? There's a getter called `params` on the `Request` object but it seems to return path params (now why would anyone break a well known pattern like this?)? Sorry, end of rant, can someone with more understanding please help?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution using only native dart,
Flow is

1. get form data as a string
2. url decode the form data string using the dart Uri class
3. again with the Uri class parse the form data to a map.

   ```
    var bodyString = await request.readAsString();
    bodyString = Uri.decodeFull(bodyString);
    final dmap = Uri.splitQueryString(bodyString);
   ```

[image]